# Sequelize eager load issue: child not associated to parent

Tags: sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize

I have the following include statement:

```
context.params.sequelize = {
    raw: false,
    include: [{
      model: organisationUsers,
      required: false,
      include: [{
        required: false,
        model: roles,
        where: roleId ? { roleId } : undefined,
      }],
    }],
}
```

I have the following data structures:
OrganisationUsers:

```
const organisationUsers = sequelizeClient.define('organisation_users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    roleId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    organisationId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      }
    });

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  organisationUsers.associate = (models) => {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    organisationUsers.belongsTo(models.organisations, { foreignKey: 'organisationId' });
    organisationUsers.belongsTo(models.roles, { foreignKey: 'roleId' });
    organisationUsers.belongsTo(models.users, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
  };
```

Roles:

```
const roles = sequelizeClient.define('roles', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        }
      },
    });

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  roles.associate = (models) => {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    roles.belongsToMany(models.permissions, { through: 'role_permissions' });
    roles.hasMany(organisationUsers(app), { foreignKey: 'roleId' });
  };
```

And Users:

```
const users = sequelizeClient.define('users', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        }
      }
    });

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  users.associate = (models) => {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    users.hasMany(organisationUsers(app), { foreignKey: 'userId' });
  };
```

If the OrganisationUsers table includes has a roleId, userId and organisationId everything works fine, but if the association is missing in the OrganisationUsers table then I get the following error:

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: roles is not associated to organisation_users!
```

I am not sure how to deal with this error, I have read about including the required: false statement, which as above you can see I have tried.

I am not sure if the issue is due to the nested include? If I remove the nested include so that it looks like this:

```
context.params.sequelize = {
        raw: false,
        include: [{
          model: organisationUsers,
        }],
    }
```

Than all works well.

If you have any ideas, advice, suggestions etc... please do let me know.

Regards,
Emir

Comment: What is `organisationUsers(app)`? This looks odd to me...

Comment: @m1ch4ls It is me initializing a feather-sequeilze model and it requires the context (app) in order to run. It is essentially the same as a standard sequelize model